# confusing bug regarding IBOutlets

Tags: iphone, ipad, viewdidload, iboutlet

Iv been breaking my head on this for long but im just not able to figure it out.

In the view Did Load method of my view controller if i try to make some changes to an imageView connected by an IBOutlet, it is non-responsive. It simply does not respond to any changes im making to IBOutlet elements. For eg: if i have an imageView in IB and its connected thru an IBOutlet and i try to set the hidden property of this ImageView it does not respond. Why this is so is beyond me.

I then added that imageView to another view and added the combination as a subView to this view. Then I could make changes to this imageView elements. But if i try to access this imageView in another method other than viewDidLoad, the application crashes. The imageView is an instance variable.

Comment: How is your ImageView property defined? Are you retaining it? e.g. @property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet ImageView *imageView

Comment: Have you checked that your ImageView property is non-null in the places you are trying to interact with it? Messages (aka 'method calls') sent to nil objects just disappear without error in Objective C, giving the impression that nothing went wrong and yet things you expect to happen don't.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely explanaintion is the the imageView is simply not connected in IB. Since the app crashes upon access, the IBOutlet is probably connected to another object instead of just being empty.